# Updating PHP Version on Ubuntu 20.04 x64 for Wordpress App

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I currently get a warning on Wordpress saying I am on an insecure version of PHP (7.3.3).

I've been trying to follow the instructions on the following page to update the version to PHP 8.1.
https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-or-upgrade-php-8-1-on-ubuntu-20-04/

I was able to install and enable php8.1 but stuck with the remaining steps. The article tells me to update a few lines in the location block of a conf file but I can't find it.

I looked at files like wordpress_https conf but could only find lines like this:

```
    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
```

Any pointers on where I need to update the reference to php8.1? It's nginx server on Obuntu 20.04. It's for a Wordpress application installed on Vultr. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your site' nginx config file. Comment out everything in your file or just backup the file and try this.

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
    server php:9000;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.test www.example.test;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.test.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.test-key.pem;


    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    
}

#The only job of this block is to redirect http to https
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.test www.example.test;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}
```

Depending on your OS, the nginx config file for your website will either be in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` or in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` .
The above configuration was taken from this [WordPress docker](https://github.com/rwahowa/ssl-Wordpress-Dev-Env-with-Docker/blob/a904c95b9e2792a50462c0a306f50a872a8b06b1/nginx/mysite.conf) dev env.

After making the edits in the correct conf file, test nginx:
`sudo nginx -t`
If all is well in the conf file restart nginx based on your system i.e :
`sudo service nginx restart`

If this works for you, ensure you search for more security details you can add in your configuration to improve it. If it does not work for you, you can generate WP specifc Nginx configurations using [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx?domains.0.php.wordPressRules=true).